# why moment js cant handle the convert :|?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using the Persian date picker and get the Unix time with it

and just want to convert to Gregorian.

here's my code:

persian date picker Unix time => 1532967741167

```
let unix = 1532967741167
let date = moment.unix(unix).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                console.log(date);
```

heres what i get from moment =>   50547-10-25

here's what I get from [epochconverter.com](https://www.epochconverter.com/)

[image]
and it's correct

any idea what's going on in here ?! :|

Comment: So what's the problem? Moment.js is doing exactly what it says it will be doing [in its documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/), as is that random website you tested, which just uses [new Date(timestamp)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). Moment will give you a date in the Gregorian year 50547, which is correct because your value is treated as _seconds_, and new Date() will give you a date in the Gregorian year 2018, which is also correct, because your value is treated as _milliseconds_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have to divide by 1000

```
let unix = 1532967741167/1000
```

this happens beacause as momentjs docs implies

> To create a moment from a Unix timestamp (seconds since the Unix
>   Epoch), use moment.unix(Number). This is implemented as
>   moment(timestamp * 1000), so partial seconds in the input timestamp
>   are included.

[here](https://momentjs.com/docs/) is the link